# how to write query in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have tried the following without success:

```
{% if forloop.counter % 2 == 0 %}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions that might help me achieve my aim? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this way

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby

Answer (score 1):

The built-in filter [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) can be used instead of the modulus operator

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
```